# How to change font-size of datetimepicker xdsoft calendar

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, django

I am using the following jQuery calendar in my html template:
https://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/

I want to increase the size of the calendar and I understood that I have to change the font-size in order to do this.

```
<script>
$(function () 
{
    $("#id_mydate").datetimepicker
    ({
        format: 'd - m - Y H:i',
        inline:true,
    });
});
</script>
```

How can I do this from html/javascript or jquery ?

I tried this:

```
<style>
   .datetimepicker {
      font-size: 20px;
   }
</style>
```

and this:

```
<style>
   #id_mydate {
      font-size: 20px;
   } 
</style>
```

without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in CSS.
I tried increasing font-size but it was not responsive. So increasing height and width will do the work.

Below are the actual classes this datepicker is using

```
    .xdsoft_datepicker {
        width: 341px !important; /*adjust accordingly*/
    }
    
    .xdsoft_calendar table, .xdsoft_time_box{
        height: 341px !important;/*adjust accordingly*/
}
```